# How to change aws dynamic default region - SAML federated users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sts

I am following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html) aws documentation to generate and use federated user login.

When i use Federation STS token to log into AWS console, it logs into Ohio(us-east-2) region by redirecting to https://console.aws.amazon.com/region/dynamic-default-region .

How to change region to N.Virginia(us-east-1) so that when i use the federation login it will automatically login into N.virginia region?

I have tried passing region=us-east-1 in the URL, however it did not work.

AWS has dynamic default region : If you signed up for an AWS account on or after May 17, 2017, the default region when you access a resource from the AWS Management Console is US East (Ohio) (us-east-2); for older accounts, the default region is either US West (Oregon) (us-west-2) or US East (N. Virginia) (us-east-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Destination` parameter (url-encoded). For example:

```
&Destination=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.aws.amazon.com%2Fconsole%2Fhome%3Fregion%3Dus-east-1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Tried .. not working.. redirecting to https://console.aws.amazon.com/region/dynamic-default-region and to us-east-2

Comment: Since i am using python code to generate URL i tried with decoded URL, it worked now with "https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1".. cheers :)